# Finding End Of Line marker of an input file

Tags: excel, vba, eol

I have a macro that will read an input file, one character at a time. I need it to find the End Of Line marker of the file. This is what I have so far:

```
While Not EOF(inFileNum)
       oneChar = Input(1, #inFileNum)
       While (oneChar <> vbLf)
```

Comment: Why not read it line by line and then parse the line character by character?

Comment: @JNevill I have to do it by character

Comment: That's going to be reaaaaaaally slow...

Comment: @braX Oh I know. It's just the way I'm instructed to do

Comment: It you open it and read one line, the end if line will be positioned at `Len(line)+1`

Comment: @TimWilliams the code Len(line)+1 will give me the end of the line of the file?

Comment: It would help a lot to explain *why* you're doing this: my suggestion was just about skipping the character-by-character part of the code.  It may be there's a better method, if we knew what you're actually doing

Comment: @TimWilliams It has to be character by character because that is what my instructions were for my class. That's all I know

Comment: @TimWilliams I understand, but how do I code it to find character 10, 12 or 13?

Comment: `If oneChar = Chr(10) or oneChar = Chr(12) or oneChar = Chr(13) Then...` I'm assuming those are consumed by this loop. I've never read a file character by character before in VBA.

Comment: @TimWilliams What would I put after the "Then" statement, or are you saying put it before  everything else in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Dim handle As Long, ch, sep, i

handle = FreeFile
Open "D:\Stuff\test.csv" For Input As handle
Do While Not EOF(handle)
    ch = Input(handle, 1)
    If Len(sep) = 0 Then
        If ch = vbLf Or ch = vbCr Then sep = ch
    Else
        'vbCr + vbLf is a valid combination,
        '  otherwise it should be a single character....
        If sep = vbCr And ch = vbLf Then sep = vbCrLf
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
Close handle

If Len(sep) > 0 Then Debug.Print "Found line separator:"
For i = 1 To Len(sep)
    Debug.Print Asc(Mid(sep, i, 1))
Next i
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but what is your "sep" variable? Is it a string?

Comment: Yes it's a string though I was lazy and left it to the default Variant type.  When the loop exits it should hold the line separator (vbCrLf, vbLf or vbCr)